# Nested query efficiency in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a table with several attributes like this:

```
id  id2  attribute
--------------------------------
 1  100  blue 
 2  100  red
 3  100  green
 4  100  white
 5  102  blue
 6  102  green
 7  102  red
 8  103  red
 9  103  blue
10  103  white
11  104  red
12  104  black
13  104  green
14  104  orange
15  105  red
16  105  blue
17  105  green
```

I want to know:
- what are the top attributes for the entries that have 'blue'?
or
- what are the top attributes for the entries that have 'blue' and 'red'?

For the second query the results should be:

```
attribute   count1
--------------------
green       3
white       2
```

I can build the query dynamically. I have this working, using this approach:

```
SELECT
  mytable.attribute,
  count(mytable.id) as count1
FROM
    mytable,
    (SELECT
     id2
    FROM
     mytable
    WHERE
     attribute in ('blue', 'red')
    GROUP BY
     id2
    HAVING
     count(distinct attribute) = 2) as t
WHERE
 mytable.id2 = t.id2
and
 attribute NOT IN ('blue', 'red')
GROUP BY
 mytable.attribute
ORDER BY
 count1 desc
```

The problem is that if the inner query has a lot of entries the while process takes too long. Can anyone suggest a way to improve this?

Comment: Are you sure the inner query should have `SELECT id` and not `SELECT id2`?

Comment: You're right. My mistake building the text for asking. I'll try your suggestion now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miguel. Note that it's quite important use the "where" expression in the subquery to gain additional performance.

```
select attribute, count(1) as count1
from mytable
where id2 in (
    select distinct t.id2
    from mytable t
    join mytable t1 on (t1.id2 = t.id2 and t1.attribute = 'red')
    where t.attribute = 'blue')
and attribute not in ('blue', 'red')
group by attribute
order by count1 desc;
```

Of course you will need some indexes. These should be enough:

```
1 > id2, attribute
2 > attribute, id2
```

Comment: Just need to add the "not in" clause, but the performance is better. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sure! I forgot that and already fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add indexes on `(attribute, id2)` and on `(id2, attribute)` and try this:

```
SELECT
    m.atttribute,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM 
    mytable AS m
  JOIN mytable AS m1
    ON  m1.attribute = 'blue'
    AND m1.id2 = m.id2
  JOIN mytable AS m2
    ON  m2.attribute = 'red'
    AND m2.id2 = m.id2
GROUP BY
    m.attribute
HAVING
    m.attribute NOT IN ('blue', 'red') 
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC ;
```

Test in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/348dd/1)**

Comment: Just tested it in the real database, after adding the (attribute, id2) index. The first index was already created. With a result of 54k rows, the original query took 9.25s and yours took 8.76s. Anything more can be done to improve it?